# Rails: Per-environment initializers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like the code in one of my initializers (in `config/initializers/`) to be run only for the `:development` environment, but not `:test` or `:production`.  What's the best way to do that?

Pasting it into `config/environments/test.rb` seems unclean, and I don't quite like wrapping the entire initializer file in an `if Rails.env == 'development' do ... end` statement.  Is there some canonical way to do this?

(Background: To speed up test load times, I'm trying to move the Barista gem into the `:development` group of my `Gemfile`, but `config/initializers/barista_config.rb` calls `Barista.configure`, so now it chokes on that in test (and production) mode.)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your only two options are putting the configuration code in `config/environments/development.rb` or wrapping your initializer code with your `if` block. You can tighten up your second option by doing `if Rails.env.development?`, though.

Comment: Another similar pattern is to use `if defined?(Foo)`, if the Foo gem is only loaded in development or test mode. [Konacha](https://github.com/jfirebaugh/konacha) recommends this, for instance.

Comment: I like the Konacha approach - avoids repeating what is already stated in the Gemfile.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is a good idea, but it's a different idea.

You could create a `config/initializers/development` directory (or `config/environments/development/initializers`), put your `barista_config.rb` in that directory, and then include anything in that directory from `config/environments/development.rb`.

I don't know if that's a good idea or not but it's at least a third option...just in case you're still thinking about this problem three and a half years after asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

Barista has a config setting for this:

```
Barista.configure do |c|
  c.env = :development
end
```

This will only recompile coffescript into js in dev mode and should speed up your tests.

Make sure you run:

```
rake barista:brew
```

before checking your code in.

https://github.com/Sutto/barista

Comment: `Barista.env` sets Barista's environment, and it defaults to `Rails.env`. Forcing it to `:development` will make it act as if your app is in development mode regardless of `Rails.env`. You shouldn't set the environment this way.