# How do you configure a different page size for production and test for Kaminari

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, kaminari

I'm running some rspec unit tests involving getting data back through kaminari paging, but the default page size for our application is 20, whereas 2 would work fine for test.

How do a set a different configuration for the default kaminari page size for test, or how do I set it up during the rspec setup for the test?

Comment: I think my issue is with a lack of rails configuration knowledge and not Kaminari specifically, so this question should be closed.

Comment: This question contains the answer that I actually need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820987/rails-per-environment-initializers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your model you can override the default per_page:

```
class Something < ActiveRecord::Base
  paginates_per Rails.env.test? ? 2 : 20
end
```

Comment: is that something I can set from the outside the class during a test setup, or is it only settable internal as you show?

Comment: I haven't tried this but it looks like you can set it in an intializer. https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/blob/master/lib/generators/kaminari/templates/kaminari_config.rb

Comment: yes, that is where I am setting it right now.  I think I probably need to ask a more general question about rails configuration instead of limiting it to Kaminari.

Comment: Based on the information in the other question and then re-reading your answer, I think I can get what I need done.

Answer (score -6):

Don't. You are supposed to test the data as similar to the production environment as possible.

Comment: This is a specific unit test related to paging that is difficult to wade through 200 lines of JSON data when 20 lines would do.