# Barista is not compiling Coffeescript files upon change

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

Rails 3.0.20
Barista 1.3.0
coffee-script 2.2.0

If I make changes to a file in app/coffescripts, I do not see the appropriate file in public/javascripts get updated.

If the file doesn't exist, it is created, but subsequent changes are never propagated.

I attempted to debug this by setting the  c.on_compilation_error setting in barista_config.rb, but didn't see any errors (are these supposed to appear in the Rails development log file)?

I am running in a different environment than "development".

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Wes

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4856430/382982) post?

Comment: I did see this post. I tried both

    `Barista.env = 'development' if Rails.env == 'MY_DEV_ENV_NAME'`

outside of the config block and then 

    `c.env = 'development' if Rails.env == 'MY_DEV_ENV_NAME'`

inside the config block and neither seemed to help.

I assume that the .coffee file is supposed to be compiled when the .js file is re-requested, is that correct?

Comment: I believe you're correct.

Have you experimented with [guard-coffeescript](https://github.com/guard/guard-coffeescript)?

Comment: Just added it. Works like a charm.

Comment: Great! Shall I submit my guard-coffeescript suggestion as an official answer?

Comment: Sure, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing [Barista](https://github.com/Sutto/barista) with [Guard::CoffeeScript](https://github.com/guard/guard-coffeescript).

> Guard::CoffeeScript compiles or validates your CoffeeScripts automatically when files are modified.